# Ruby Capybara error - port_prober.rb:28:in `initialize': A socket operation encountered a dead network. - bind(2)

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run the following Ruby code on a new machine

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require "selenium-webdriver"

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Capybara.app_host = 'http://www.google.com'

module MyCapybaraTest
  class Test
    include Capybara::DSL
      def test_google
         puts "starting..."
         visit('/')
         puts "done..."
      end
  end
end

t = MyCapybaraTest::Test.new
t.test_google
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
C:/ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver   /common/port_prober.rb:28:in `initialize': A socket operation encountered a dead network. - bind(2) (Errno::ENETDOWN)
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: It worked on my local machine, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Could you have a chance to check your connections/ports?

Comment: Local firewall is off & all ports ok - Im at work though and behind a proxy - though if I change the address to http://localhost I get the same error

Comment: This code works fine. strace it.

Answer (score 1):

This error, as you might have notice, happens because the system detected that your internet is down. I see you checked your firewall, are you using unusual network interfaces? Can you debug it with wireshark?